# I am accessing records of dates: how to assign a value when a particular date is not present?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I want to get data from database regarding dates.

Suppose I want to access data from June,1st to August,1st from my database. If, for example, there are no records for the dates 5,6 and 10 how to assign a count of zero for these dates ?

This is just a simple scenario. If we dont have data for 1 month then how to assign zero for all the days?

Comment: can you reformat/rephrase your question I don't understand what you want to do, an example could also help

Comment: @Umi I tried my best to understand and rephrase your question accordingly, please correct me if I misunderstood something; and if some english mothertongue can make it sound "right" it would be even better

Comment: i want to show no. of sold item per date and i am showing it by datewise.if i want data from june 1 to aug 1.for some das i dont have data or nothing is sold.for that dates how to assign zero count.for example:select date,count(*) from sample where date >"some date" and <"some date";this will give me set of dates but for some dates database dont have records. so how to found that dates and assign count zero to that dates.thats my problem.Thanx in advance!

Comment: Hi, I think you can do this easily if you combine both php and mysql together. You create a php loop for relevant date range. Then compaire with the retrieved dataset. You can create records with '0' values for not existing data sets.

Answer (score 0):

AFAI understand your question, you must study [`Coalesce`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) or [`IFNULL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull)

Answer (score 0):

You could intitialize an array of dates before you access database, with values for each day in the range of search being zero. Then you fill the values for days that you have in database and rest remain unchanged, as zero.